# How to populate a map using Batch

Tags: apex, batch, map

So I have to create a map using an object implementing the batch interface. I have used the Database.stateful interface to make sure all instances of the batch are inserting into the same table. The problem is, the table has the a child/parent relationship with the child as the key and the parent as the value. I need to wait for the table to populate completely and then do certain actions to the table. My question is, how do I make the table is fully populated by all of the instances before proceeding with the rest of the operations in my execute method? I have to pull information from the table and insert them into a list, and i originally thought of doing it inside the finish() method. But it seems like you can not do any operations inside the finish() method. Following is my code:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> agreements){
        //maybe create table in here?
         for(sObject agree : agreements){
            allAgreements.add(agree);
            //System.debug(AgreementHierarchySupport.allAgreements.get(0));
         }

         populateMap(allAgreements);
         for(sObject agreement: allAgreements){
            parent = mapAgreement.get(agreement.Id);
            toInsert.add(this.insertHelper(agreement.Id, parent, this.findRoot(agreement.Id)));

         } 
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {


        //System.debug(agree.get(0));
        upsert toInsert;
    }
```

Comment: You can operations in the finish method. You may need to schedule a follow up batch from the finish method to process the results by using system.scheduleBatch() method